# Is there a way to use EL to get the current value of an h:inputText field?

Tags: jsf, seam, el

I'm new to JSF and EL, and was wondering if there is a way to use EL to get the current value of an h:inputText field. Am I doing it wrong, or is it possible at all?

Thanks,
-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on your comment) If you want to validate it server-side then you should look at an Ajax library like [Richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces).

You can then easily add an ajax call to your input field

```
<h:inputText id="myInput" value="#{myBean.myValue}">
   <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"/>
</h:inputText>
```

When you change the text the Ajax call will update your model on the Server-side. If you have a validator then you can add it to the inputText tag or use the action attribute on the support tag to call another method.

Comment: Wow! As it turns out, I am using richfaces. I'm going to give this a shot right now...

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot for the help! I do have one nitpick, however. If I make a change to a field that would cause a confirm prompt to come up (this happens when the user clicks a 'save' button, since many fields need to be validated together), and then directly go to the save button, the prompt doesn't come up. However, if I click on some other field (to lose focus, and therefore cause a model update), and then click save, the confirm prompt will show. So the question is, can a blur be used in the save button somehow? (I'm already using the onClick for prompting)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. What causes the confirm prompt to appear?

Comment: To paint a better picture: There are several fields, which are validated together when the user clicks a 'save' button. If they fail validation, a confirm prompt comes up. Since ajax is used to update the fields on the server-side while they are being edited, its possible to edit a field and click the save button (immediately after) without ajax updating the server-side value. However, if one edits a field and 'tabs around' or anything else to trigger the 'onchange' event, everything works normally. So, is there a way to force an ajax update when the save button is clicked, just to be sure?

Comment: Make the save button a a4j:commandButton and set the value of the eventsQueue attribute to be the same as the eventsQueue attribute on your support tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are looking for...

With this code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myInput" value="#{myBean.myValue}"/>
```

The value of the input field, at the creation of the HTML page, will be equal to the value of the *myValue* property of the bean *myBean*.

If the value is changed by the user, JSF will automatically update the value of *myBean.myValue* when the form will be submitted.

If you need to get the value of the input on the client side, i.e. using Javascript, you need to do the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getInputTextValue() {
        var valueOfInput = document.getElementById("myForm:myInput").value;
    }
</script>
```

Note that you must prefix the ID by the ID of the form that contains the input ("**myForm:**myInput").

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! Basically, what I need to do is take the input and validate it server-side (have a rather large bean method for this). Then, if it fails validation, I want to give a warning dialogue to the user, preferably with javascript, since that seems to be the easiest way. Now that I know how to get the current value of the field with javascript, I'll see if there's a way to call a bean method and do something with the return value.